# AMOLED Pixel Behavior

Tags: super-amoled

Do AMOLED pixels automatically turn off when displaying a black part of an image? Or is a special app required for this?

Comment: This is actually independent of Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AMOLED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMOLED) displays use [Active Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_matrix), which controls each pixel individually (allowing black pixels to be turned off completely). Since this is integrated into the design and build of the screen (and mostly what makes a screen AMOLED), the turning off of black pixels happens automatically.

Comment: How about whites? Are they made up of RGB or is there a specific white pixel?

Comment: @adelrahimi White is made up of RedGreenBlue or, depending on the device, RedGreenBlueGreen.